# Can we get all <li> values using React ref on its <ul> parent?

Tags: reactjs, react-ref

Can we get all li values by using React Refs on its UL parent? like forward refs or  children kind of???

I'm expecting to do the below using React Ref.

---

```
let listItem = getElementsByTagName('li');

let anchor;

let listAnchorVal;

for(let i = 0; i < listItem.length; i++){
   anchor = listItem[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
   listAnchorVal= anchor.textContent || anchor.innerText;
}
```

---

My React code below

```
const listItems = React.createRef();

const handleKeyUp = () => {
     console.log(listItems.current.value) :(
};

return (
    <div>
        <input type="text" className="list-filter-input" onKeyUp={handleKeyUp} placeholder="Search names...." />
         <span style={{position:"absolute", right:"925px", marginTop:"1.5%"}}><i className="fa fa-fw fa-search"></i></span>
            <ul className="list-filter-ul" ref={listItems}>
                <li><a href="#">Deepak</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Mytidbit</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Hello</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">World</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Chris</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Bestie</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sugar</a></li>
            </ul>
    </div>
```

This is a list filter i'm trying to implement.

onKeyUp on input, I wish to do the below. Do you think using state to have li values to achieve this filter is unavoidable? I'm thinking of other possibilities than using a state.

```
     onKeyUp(e){         
      listItemValues.filter(val=>{
return val.toLowerCase().includes(e.target.value.toLowerCase()))
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what goal you are trying to accomplish? With React, the DOM is a representation of data that you typically store in plain JavaScript objects. Meaning, you only rarely need to inspect the DOM with functions like you are doing; that data is already available elsewhere in your code.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you want to achieve. Might help you get a better solution.

Comment: @RossAllen  Mohit Mutha ...updated my question.

Comment: Aha, I understand. Okay, let me write an answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A key concept when using React or Vue or similar framework is that your UI should always be a representation of your data; your UI doesn't store any extra information. In your case, you can pull out the names into an array:

```
// The value in the input is state, it needs to be stored as it changes.
const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState("");

// The names to render are data, they are stored in a plain old array.
const names = [
    "Deepak",
    "Mytidbit",
    "Hello",
    "World",
    "Chris",
    "Bestie",
    "Sugar",
];

// The filtered list is derivable from state + data, it doesn't need
// to be stored separately
const filteredNames = names.filter(val => 
    val.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue.toLowerCase())
);

const handleKeyUp = (event) => {
    setSearchValue(event.target.value);
};

return (
    <div>
        <input type="text" className="list-filter-input" onKeyUp={handleKeyUp} placeholder="Search names...." value={searchValue} />
         <span style={{position:"absolute", right:"925px", marginTop:"1.5%"}}><i className="fa fa-fw fa-search"></i></span>
            <ul className="list-filter-ul">
                {filteredNames.map(name => (
                    <li key={name}><a href="#">{name}</a></li>
                ))}
            </ul>
    </div>
);
```